# SQL a SELECT within a SELECT? Northwind (Microsoft)

Tags: sql, select, northwind

First of all, I'm practicing with `Northwind` database (**Microsoft** creation).

The table design I'm working with is:
[image]

The question I'm trying to solve is:

> Which Product is the most popular?  (number of items)

Well, my query was:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
 P.ProductName
FROM 
 Products P,
 [Order Details] OD,
 Orders O,
 Customers C
WHERE 
 C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
 and O.OrderID = OD.OrderID
 and OD.ProductID = P.ProductID
 and P.UnitsInStock = (SELECT MAX(P.UnitsInStock) Items
                        FROM Products P)
```

Now, I had exactly **one** result as they asked:

`ProductName
1 Rhönbräu Klosterbier`

Yet, I doublt that my query was good. Do I really need a SELECT within a SELECT?

It feels like duplication for some reason.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Does the most units in stock necessarily equate to the most popular product? I don't think that is always a true statement (It could even be the opposite in fact.).

To me the question is asking, which is the most popular product *sold*. If you think about it that way, you'd be looking at the amount sold for each product and selecting the product with the most sold.

Does that make sense?

**With regards to your specific query**, the query only utilizes the Products table. You make joins, but they are not used at all in the query and should get overlooked by the query optimizer.

I would personally rewrite your query as the following:

```
SELECT
    P.ProductName
FROM 
    Products P
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        MAX(P.UnitsInStock) AS Items
     FROM Products P) maxProd
ON P.UnitsInStock= maxProd.Items
```

**About your question**, it is perfectly acceptable to utilize a subquery (the select in the where clause). It is even necessary at times. Most of the time I would use an Inner Join like I did above, but if the dataset is small enough, it shouldn't make much difference with query time.

In this scenario, you should rethink the question that is being asked and think about what being the most popular item means.

**Rethinking the problem:**

Let's look at the datasets that you've shown above. Which could be used to tell you how many products have been sold? A customer would have to *order* a product, right? Looking at the two tables that are potentially applicable, one contains details about number of items sold, *quantity*, or you could think of popularity in terms of the number of times appearing in orders. Start with that dataset and use a similar methodology to what you've done, but perhaps you'll have to use a sum and group by. Why? Perhaps more than one customer bought the item.

The problem with the dataset is it doesn't tell you the name of the product. It only gives you the ID. There is a table though that has this information. Namely, the Products table. You'll notice that both tables have the Product ID variable, and you are able to join on this.

Comment: Could you help me writing the query you said about the 'sold' parameter according to the table design? I think that you are the one who is right. @houstonwp

Comment: I will add on to my answer above to include more details on the 'sold' parameter.

Comment: Consider what "most popular" may mean: 1. most number sold; 2. exist in most number of orders. Depending of your choice the answer may differ.

Answer (score 0):

To get the most popular product (bestselling product) use query

```
SELECT ProductName, MAX(SumQuantity) 
FROM (
    SELECT P.ProductName ProductName,
        SUM(OD.Quantity) SumQuantity
    FROM [Order Details] OD
    LEFT JOIN Product P ON
        P.ProductId = OD.ProductID
    GROUP BY OD.ProductID
    ) Res;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the most popular product by counting the number of orders placed on each product .And the one with most number of order will be the most popular product.

Below script will give you the most popular product based on the the number of orders placed .

```
;WITH cte_1
AS(
SELECT p.ProductID,ProductName, count(OrderID) CNT
FROM Products p 
    JOIN [Order Details] od ON p.ProductID=od.ProductID
GROUP BY p.ProductID,ProductName)
SELECT  top 1 ProductName
FROM cte_1
ORDER BY CNT desc
```

if you are using SQL server 2012 or any higher version, use '`with ties`' for fetching multiple products having same order count.

```
;WITH cte_1
AS(
SELECT p.ProductID,ProductName, count(OrderID) CNT
FROM Products p 
    JOIN [Order Details] od ON p.ProductID=od.ProductID
GROUP BY p.ProductID,ProductName)
SELECT  top 1 with ties ProductName
FROM cte_1
ORDER BY CNT desc
```

In your sample code,you tried to pull the product with maximum stock held. since you joined with other tables (like order details etc) you are getting multiple results for the same product. if you wanted to get a product with maximum stock,you can use any of the following script.

```
SELECT ProductName
FROM Products P 
WHERE P.UnitsInStock = (SELECT MAX(P.UnitsInStock) Items
                    FROM Products P)
```

OR

```
SELECT top 1 ProductName
FROM Products P 
ORDER BY P.UnitsInStock desc
```

OR

```
SELECT top 1 with ties ProductName --use with ties in order to pull top products having same UnitsInStock 
FROM Products P 
ORDER BY P.UnitsInStock desc
```